# $watch in a link function of my directive is not updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have this directive which tries to watch for changes in a json object on scope. The JSON object is retrieved using a restangular based service, but somehow the $watch seems to be executed only once, logging 'undefined'.

The directive is used in the index.html of the app, so I suspect this has to do with the controller only working for the specific view or form...is there a way to get the directive to see those changes?

update: figured I could just call the TextsService from the directive itself, seems like a good solution to the problem. If anyone has better suggestions I'd welcome them still though.

service:

```
angular.module('main').service('TextsService', function(Restangular) {

    this.getTexts = function(jsonRequestBase, jsonRequest, callback) {

        Restangular.one(jsonRequestBase, jsonRequest).get().then(
            function(texts) {
                callback(texts);
            }
        );
    };
});
```

call in controller:

```
TexstService.getTexts("content", "file.json", function (texts) {
    $scope.mytest = texts;
});
```

directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective',
function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl:'test.html',
        transclude: true,

        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {

            scope.$watch('mytest', function(){
                console.log(scope.mytest);
            }, true);
```

Comment: Add `$scope.$apply()` inside the callback after you set `$scope.mytest = texts;`

Comment: Then I get Error: $digest already in progress, probably restangular is already doing something there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured I could just call the TextsService from the directive itself, seems like a good solution to the problem. If anyone has better suggestions I'd welcome them still though.

Answer (score 0):

Create the variable with null before receving it. Maybe that works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your directive's scope does not know about the `mytest` variable. You need to define the binding when you define the directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective',
  function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        myDirective: '='
      },
      restrict: 'A',
      templateUrl:'test.html',
      transclude: true,
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('myDirective', function(newVal){
            console.log(newVal);
        }, true);
    };
  }
);
```

This will get whatever variable is assigned to the directive attribute and watch its' value.

And your directive in the view should look like this to bind it to the 'mytest':

```
<div my-directive="mytest"></div>
```